# Import module works in PyCharm but giving error in terminal python 3.7

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, python-3.7, importerror

I have project where I have created multiple python files based on its usage. It works completely fine when I run from the pycharm. However, when I run the same from the terminal, I get the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataflow'

I need to make the dataflow out of this and need to deploy and it is giving an error while doing so.

Folder structure of the project, this works when I run from PyCharm

[image]

Error while running it from the terminal

[image]

Comment: Pycharm is set up to use the exact same environment?

Comment: yes, I have set python 3.7 env in the pycharm and also same is getting reflected in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Adducated guess, runs pychar your code in venv too? If not you might check if you installed the package that is missing in your venv.

**Update**

if you intent to have a dataflow package that you want to import and use the modules in it you need a __init__.py file in your dataflow folder. this makes it a package for python. If you want to use the modules in dataflow with the . in an import you need to do an import in __init__.py

like so

```
import .driver_main
```

this makes stuff from driver_main available in dataflow   but better practice would be to specifiy what you want to access from driver_main like

```
from .driver_main import MyDriver
```

this will gibe you access to my driver via

```
dataflow.MyDriver
```

If you really just want to acces stuff from one module on the same lvl you should  able to do so with the same approach. so in you exaple you showed in the picture try to change

```
from dataflow import driver_main
```

to

```
   from . import driver_main
```

this would apply to an import in a module on the same lvl as driver_main.py like app.py

**Update on Comments in original post**

btw the env in pychar has nothing to do with the venv in the console. You simply telling pycharm to use python 3.7 but with your venv you copy binaries in a folder stucture. that said if you run an virtual environment all stuff you pip there gets copied in this folder structure not in the global site-packages. This means if you installed stuff global you wont have it right away in the virtual env and the other way around!

Comment: It is not the package which is available in PyPi, but it is the files that I have created. You can look it into the screenshot.